# Which one is best to use for null or empty check

Tags: java, collections

Difference between listobj.isEmpty() and collectionUtils.isEmpty(list)

Comment: First one will fail if the list itself is null.  Why not be an experimentalist and try it?

Comment: Jack's answer below is the correct answer. The short version of his answer is "it depends." The latter will look prettier if you want to skip null-checks in your code; the former is better if you know you aren't dealing with null variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CollectionUtils.isEmpty(Collection<?> collection)` is just a null-safe version of the native method, sort of `return collection == null || collection.isEmpty()`.

As a rule of thumb you shouldn't need the helper method because [you shouldn't have](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12777/are-null-references-really-a-bad-thing) `null` values. It's safer to have an empty collection that a value which is `null` to represent the empty collection. This can be enforced in multiple ways, for example by using `final` on member variables and such